# Vigenere Attack Identification and Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, computer-science, vigenere

I have been trying to detect a block of data encrypted with the Vigenere algorithm for a long time..I want to determine which encryption algorithm the data I have is encrypted.I don't want to reach the original version of the data.

In the first case, since I have the original version of the data, I can understand that it is encrypted with a little comparison, but as I said, I am having trouble at the point of which cryptological function is used.

Only the function in my hand (assuming that I have the data in an unencrypted state) should be able to say that it is encrypted with the Vigenere algorithm.

What kind of method should I follow here, what should I do? I am waiting for your help and ideas. Thank you very much in advance.

**(I looked at the Kasiski method, but it works to find the key value of the encryption algorithm and to decrypt it.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and it should be rather asked @ [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Modern ciphers are IND-CPA secure. In that case it is impossible to find the cipher used even if the adversary has full control over the input of the function. Quite often the only way to check which algorithm is used is to partially decrypt the ciphertext.